# How should M&TV's "Ask Question" page be customised?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The "Ask a question" wizard is now live network-wide: [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/398063). Ours is very plain right now, but parts of it are customisable: *(shortened; see the main Meta post for the full version)*

> - **The "welcome modal" for new askers** (seen with the default text in screenshot 1), everything between the title and "Before you post..."
> - The full contents of **the "Draft your question" sidebar**
> - **The text in the tag popover**, between "Tags help the right people..." and the bullet points.
> - **The placeholder text in the title field** (text only).
> - **The warning text shown in the "Review your question" sidebar**, regex-based
> - **Tag-related error messages**, regex-based

The first step of changing these is obviously a Meta discussion, so here goes. What should we put there?

---

<sub>Phrasing self-plagiarised from [the same question I asked on SFF's meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12936/98028).</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Stating in the "Draft your question" sidebar that recommendations and identification requests are off-topic would be useful, IMO. The same could be said of any of [the off-topic reasons](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but these two being the most common, an additional warning can't hurt.

The review phase does throw a warning if you try to add the [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) tag (as it already used to), but is not enough by itself, as some people only tag their story-ID question with, say, [thriller](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thriller) or [indian-cinema](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-cinema) and would thus not see said warning.

Answer (score 3):

Not the most important, but the "Draft your question" sidebar currently spells "tv" in lowercase letters. I'd say this should be switched to uppercase "TV". Related discussion at [Is your question about tv or TV?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4492/63559).

The same goes for the placeholder text in the title.

Comment: Posting this as a separate answer since people may want to vote differently about this request than on the story-ID one.